# How to disable site's CSS and use just mine or overwrite their just for a specific HTML fragment

Tags: html, css

I'm generating HTML + CSS code that people can put on their websites

The problem is that for example my HTML code uses `<table>`

which is very often styled by their bootstrap or whatever CSS they are using

and their CSS causes mine to break really hard

So, the question is:

Is there something that will allow me to "isolate" my HTML + CSS from their?

or maybe rename `table` tag to something else that will still behave like table, but not be stylized by their `table` CSS? like `myTable` although table's not the only tag that I'm using

Example, something like `<noscript>` block

```
<somebody's_Site>
<header>SomeSite</header>
    <disable_css>
        <style>
            MyCSS
        </style>
        
        <table>
            MyTable
        <table>
    </disable_css>
<footer>Contact</footer>
<somebody's_Site>
```

Constrains:

I cannot use it as iframe + loading content from other server because it has to be just static HTML+CSS

I'd really, really want to avoid JS.

Any ideas how to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your selectors more specific.  Which could be as simple as wrapping your content in a `<div>`:

```
<div id="axelly-div-wrapper">
  <table>
    <!-- etc. -->
  </table>
</div>
```

As long as that wrapping element is uniquely identified, use that as the selector:

```
#axelly-div-wrapper > table {
    color: red;
    /* etc. */
}
```

It's still *possible* for users to override your styling, but they'd have to *explicitly* do it by:

1. Modifying your code; or
2. Targeting your `id` value; or
3. *Re-using* your `id` value; or
4. Making sloppy use of `!important`

Basically, the more specific your styling is in identifying the element(s) being styled, the more explicit consuming pages would have to be to override it.  You could wrap the whole thing in an element, you could populate all your elements with specific `id` values and target only those, etc.

Comment: That seems to be good idea, but I struggle with making it work as expected. I tried also iframe and it works perfectly, but the only problem is that I have to resize iframe with javascript :(

Comment: @Axelly: An `<iframe>` is likely to be more trouble than it's worth for this problem, at least in my opinion.  What about this approach isn't working for you?

Comment: I have no idea, I've prepared the css with better specified CSS, but when I paste it into other websites (SO, blogs) then it breaks - here's whole code https://pastebin.mozilla.org/AOeW292Y/raw

Comment: @Axelly: "Breaks" how, exactly?  If you "have no idea" how it isn't working then what makes you believe it isn't working?  When I [test your code](https://jsfiddle.net/6yq12tmj/1/) by surrounding it with another element and styling that element, everything works as expected.

Comment: For example I edited DOM in your post and pasted this HTML there and it did indeed appear there, but the background-color was different https://i.imgur.com/wAcQFC7.png

Comment: @Axelly: Seeing the actual test would be more helpful then seeing just a picture of the result of the test.

Comment: Fair, click right click on first word in your post (Make), then Inspect element, then in Dev console use right click on that node: `<p> Make your selectors...` and click "Edit as HTML" and replace that `p tag` html with my code

Comment: @Axelly: Mine looks different because I'm browsing in dark mode.  But this sounds like a good opportunity for you to use those same browser debugging tools to investigate the styling that you're observing and see why it's rendering the way it is.  It's entirely possible, even likely, that there's simply some styling you haven't explicitly defined/overridden in your element(s).

Comment: I managed to fix it with important, but while that works on SO, then on some other sites it breaks (e.g table's columns widths). Ehh, it feels like iframe will be relatively universal